# Animating a recursive backtracking algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to create a live demo of a backtracking algorithm (with simple forward checking) in javascript. I've gotten the algorithm down pat in its recursive form, but now I'm stuck trying to animate it using javascript's `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, which I'm assuming would require me to convert the recursive solution to an iterative one. Here's the function (rewritten to be a little more general):

```
function solve(model) {
    if (model.isSolved()) return true;
    var chosen = chooseVariable(model); //could be random or least constrained
    var domain = model.getDomain(chosen);
    var i, assn;
    for (i = 0; i < domain.length; i++) {
        assn = domain[i];
        model.set(chosen, assn);
        if (solve(model)) return true;
        else model.undo();
    }
    return false;

}
```

As you can see, I've made it so that the model can undo it's own actions, rather than having a separate action stack or cloning the model at each level of recursion. Is there a way to convert the function above into one that could be used with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`? Would I have to significantly change the model/add another stack to keep track of the chosen variable/attempted assignments? Do I need a closure with mutating variables? I'm mostly looking for pseudocode to point me in the right direction.

Comment: couldn't you just implement a kind of sleep and update your animation in another animationLoop()?

Comment: Is that really a viable solution? I was under the impression that sleep implementations in js are bad practice given that javascript is single-threaded/asynchronous.

Comment: @fordprefect: No, there's no `sleep` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming this require me to convert the recursive solution to an iterative one.

No, right the other way round. Yours still is iterative in some parts (the `for`-loop).

You will have to make the steps asynchronous, so that each step takes a callback which is fired when its animation is done and you can continue. Since you will want to animate every single iteration step, you will have to make them asynchronous with a recursive-like callback - [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Here's how:

```
function solve(model, callback) {
    if (model.isSolved())
        return callback(true);
    var chosen = chooseVariable(model); // could be random or least constrained
    var domain = model.getDomain(chosen);
    var i = 0, assn;
    (function nextStep() {
        if (i < domain.length) {
            assn = domain[i];
            model.set(chosen, assn);
            solve(model, function(solved) {
                if (solved)
                    callback(true);
                else {
                    model.undo();
                    i++;
                    nextStep();
                }
            });
        } else
            callback(false);
    })();
}
```

Now you can simply make this recursive variant asynchronous by introducing `setTimeout` where you need it (usually after displaying the `model` state):

```
function solve(model, callback) {
    if (model.isSolved())
        return callback(true);
    var chosen = chooseVariable(model); // could be random or least constrained
    var domain = model.getDomain(chosen);
    var i = 0, assn;
    (function nextStep() {
        if (i < domain.length) {
            assn = domain[i];
            model.set(chosen, assn);
            solve(model, function(solved) {
                if (solved)
                    callback(true);
                else {
                    model.undo();
                    i++;
                    setTimeout(nextStep, 100);
                }
            });
        } else
            setTimeout(callback, 100, false);
    })();
}
```

Comment: Found a bug! In my implementation of your code, backtracking and reassignment are properly delayed but consecutive assignments are still instantaneous. I'll try to fix it on my own before I accept this answer. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Yes, you probably want to put the assignment steps in a `setTimeout(function(){ var domain = …; setTimeout(function(){ var i=0,…  ; },100); },100);` cascade. This is only complicated when you're dealing with control flow (loops etc) which has to be rewritten (and I've shown you how) but now that execution is quite linear (with recursive calls) you can basically insert such delays wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could program it asynchronously using for example deferreds. jQuery provides an implementation of deferreds and you could have a look at this example which uses timeouts:

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/#example-0

Of course you need only one timeout which always resolves (succeeds).